# Construct an array of indices of std::tuple types

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

Given a tuple containing elements of distinct types (no two are the same):

```
typedef std::tuple<bool, char, int, float, double, std::string> t1;
```

and a tuple type containing elements restricted to those types (duplicates and omissions are possible, but no additional types):

```
typedef std::tuple<char, int, int, double, std::string, int, double> t2;
```

How can I construct a `std::array` containing the indices of the matching element in `t1` for the elements in `t2`?

```
{1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4}
```

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to use these indices to extract elements from t1, you can just use `std::get<T>(t1)`, where `T` is each of the types within `t2`

Comment: @Eric My ultimate goal is to identify t2 element type with the index in t1 (now in my code t1 is std::variant). And using this 'type_id' I serialize and deserialize t2 to/from a binary stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's doable.
Let's give [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple) and related machinery a workout.

First, code a way to get the index of the single unique match for an arbitrary type in something tuple-like:

```
template <class T, class U, std::size_t... N>
static constexpr auto tuple_index_impl(std::index_sequence<N...>) noexcept {
    static_assert((std::size_t() + ... + std::is_same_v<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, U>>) == 1,
        "There is no single exact match");
    return (0 + ... + (N * std::is_same_v<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, U>>));
}
template <class T, class U>
static constexpr std::size_t
tuple_index_v = tuple_index_impl<T, U>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<U>>());
```

A pity that's not part of the standard-library already.

Next, use that to get all the indices and put them into a `std::array`:

```
template <class T, class U, std::size_t... N>
constexpr auto indices_impl(std::index_sequence<N...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(N)>{tuple_index_v<std::tuple_element_t<N, U>, T>...};
}
template <class T, class U>
constexpr auto indices() noexcept {
    return indices_impl<T, U>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<U>>());
}
```

An example-use:

```
for (auto x : indices<t1, t2>())
    std::cout << x << '\n';
```

See it [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df4f0811d06bcae).

Comment: Great code! But I did not figure out yet where is the last index. Your result is {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2}, but there should be {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4}

Comment: Fixed that: I took the length from the wrong tuple.

Comment: You multiply size_t by bool, see 'N * std::is_same_v...'. Should I change this in my code or leave it as is? Is not std::size_t() better than 0?

Comment: I multiply it because I want the unique index where std::is_same is true, and that's the easiest way to get it. I used implicit conversion from bool to 0/1 in the static_assert too.